# Latex / PsTricks

Tags: pstricks

1. Generate Graphical Representation of Lagrange Mean Value theorem.

You can take the function f(x) = x(x-1)(x-2) over the itnerval [0, 1/2].

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What is precisely the question here? (Note that this is not TeXing service, but a Q & A site.)

Comment: This looks like taken directly from a homework question

Comment: `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=\x*(\x-1)*(\x-2);}]
\begin{axis}[axis lines=center,enlargelimits=0.3,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$f(x)$]
\addplot[domain=0:1/2] {f(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\psset{llx=-0.5cm,lly=-0.5cm,labelFontSize=\footnotesize}
\begin{psgraph}[xticksize=-4pt 0,Dx=0.2,Dy=0.2,
      arrows=->](0,0)(-0.1,-0.1)(0.6,0.6){5cm}{5cm}
   \psplot[linewidth=2pt,linecolor=blue,algebraic]{0}{0.5}{x*(x-1)*(x-2) }
\end{psgraph}   

\end{document}
```

[image]